# Check all checkboxes in first column of gridview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

I have done the following code to check all checkboxes in first column of gridview but it works only for IE 5.0 to 8.0 and gives a Javascript error when i run it in IE 9 and above as "Function Expected". Can anyone guide me through this ?

```
function selectAllItems(gridID, hdnSelectedValuesID, pagedGrid, chkSelectAllCtrl) {

var hdnSelectedValuesID = document.getElementById(hdnSelectedValuesID);
if (chkSelectAllCtrl != null) {
    hdnSelectedValuesID.value = '';
    var rowLength = document.getElementById(gridID).rows.length;
    var upperLimitOnRows = 0;
    var elementA = '';

    if (pagedGrid)
        upperLimitOnRows = rowLength - 1;
    else
        upperLimitOnRows = rowLength;

    //Set the other checkboxes in the item section to selected    
    for (var Count = 1; Count < upperLimitOnRows; Count++) {
        //Check all checkboxes in the first column of grid
        document.getElementById(gridID).rows(Count).cells(0).childNodes(0).checked = chkSelectAllCtrl.checked; // Error In this Line
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How are you calling your function, and what is your html ?

Comment: @JDE I am calling my function onClick of CheckBox. like this "return selectAllItems('" + gvFilterRecords.ClientID + "','" + hdnTransactions.ClientID + "', " + gvFilterRecords.AllowPaging.ToString().ToLower() + ", this);"

Comment: I think your this is wrong. gimmie a sec.  Could you add your html or replicate it in a codepen?

Comment: @JDE its working fine with IE 7 and 8 but not working when i run in IE 9 and above. I am setting the attributes from codebehind for Checkbox <br/> chkSelectAll.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return selectAllItems('" + gvFilterRecords.ClientID + "','" + hdnTransactions.ClientID + "', " + gvFilterRecords.AllowPaging.ToString().ToLower() + ", this);");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use square brackets instead of parentheses:

```
var grid = document.getElementById(gridID);
for (var count = 1; count < upperLimitOnRows; count++) {
   grid.rows[count].cells[0].childNodes[0].checked = chkSelectAllCtrl.checked;
}
```

N.B. The check box may also be the child node 1 instead of 0. That is what I see with a TemplateField but it may be different for a CheckBoxField or an auto-generated column.